# Optimize Long for-loop with a Select Case in it

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, select, optimization

I have to iterate over big loops and use a Case Select structure. I loop first over the requested params (which are normally about 10) and then for each match I loop over the list of files (which is about 10k). The code has the following structure but with lots more Cases.

```
For i = 1 To dNumColumns Step 1 
Debug.Print(CStr(Now() & " Column: " & UCase(vInHeaders(1,i))))

    Select Case UCase(Cols(1,i))
        Case "NAME":
            row = 1
            For Each t In vT
                vTestsValues(row, i) = t.Name : row += 1
            Next
        Case "DATE":
            row = 1
            For Each t In vT
                vTestsValues(row, i) = t.Date : row += 1
            Next
        Case "PATH":
            row = 1
            For Each t In vT
                vTestsValues(row, i) = t.Path : row += 1
            Next
        Case "RIGHTS":
            row = 1
            For Each t In vT
                vTestsValues(row, i) = t.Rights : row += 1
            Next
        Case "AUTHOR":
            row = 1
            For Each t In vT
                vTestsValues(row, i) = t.Author : row += 1
            Next
        Case "TYPE":
            row = 1
            For Each t In vT
                vTestsValues(row, i) = t.Type : row += 1
            Next
        Case "VERSION":
            row = 1
            For Each t In vT
                vTestsValues(row, i) = t.Version : row += 1
            Next
        Case Else
            row = 1
            For Each t In vT
                vTestsValues(row, i) = "ERR"
                row += 1
            Next
        End Select

dNumColumns is a Variant Array, containing Strings;
vT is a Variant Array containing a Document Object
```

What would be the most efficient way to add these results to vTestsValues? Already tried with a "For Each t In vT" (usually has 10k items) and nest in it the "For i = 1 To dNumColumns" loop to select the Cases and got slightly slower performance. Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: Are the data sorted? Because if so you can do a binary search.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the declaration and content of each variable. With 10000 rows and 10 columns, it should execute in less than 100ms. Make sure that all the values are loaded in an array and loop over the rows with a `For To` instead of a `For Each in`.

Comment: The `Debug.Print` will slow down things...

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each t In vT
        vTestsValues(row, i) = CallByName(t, Cols(1,i), vbGet)  : row += 1
    Next
```